# Return 2 different arrays from a same php function

Tags: php, function

I have `two multidimensional associative arrays` as a result by getting the function parameter.Then I must have to return these two arrays from this function..Can we do that or any other tricky way to do that in php?

Tricky way means getting together that two arrays in single one and get from that like that..Suggesting as a code is better..

Thank You...

Comment: i think you need to look at list function in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: You can return an array that contains both those multi-dimensional associative arrays you get as a result, but you can not return 2 variables.

Comment: can you provide the syntax..

Comment: @jana This would suffice,         return [
            'var1' => $array1,
            'var2' => $array2
        ];. And you can use the one you want afterwards.

Comment: @ user340764 thank you for the start up

Comment: @Jana Your question is too broad and you should include a [mcve] of what you tried, but you can also pass the array as references to the function `function get_arrays($source, &$dest1, &$dest2) { $dest1 = $source[0]; $dest2 = $source[1]; }` and by passing `$dest` and `$dest2` by reference (Using `&`) to the function you'll be able to assign a value to those variables from the function itself

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to create an object and add these two different array in that object and send that object out of the php method. 
This way the two arrays are send out. 
Other Alternative is to have an an array of arrays, 
[["abc","addf"],[1,2,3]]

you can use either of the ways to send your output out.